# List index out of range error when adding a new dictionary key with iterating index numbers on said list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, index-error

Not gonna go into too many specifics on the background. The myquery thing runs a script that pulls from my work database. Everything gets put into a list. From there it's supposed to dump everything into a Google Sheet, one line at a time. Worked great when it was just two variables I had to worry about and I could use something binary like a dictionary. Well, now I got more; 4 categories, each need to be on their own line.

I just need to split up the list (rawskudata) into a bunch of smaller lists (componant) assigned to a dictionary (skuandimages). The problem is on this line:

> skuandimages[c_list] = [rawskudata[int(c_sku)], rawskudata[int(c_img_url)], rawskudata[int(c_name)], rawskudata[int(c_quantity)]]

and I get IndexError: list index out of range.

based on me staring at it for literally two straight hours and making every google search result for "indexerror" purple, this SHOULD work. the list it's pulling from DOES have the index number. i checked with all sorts of print statements. why. why is it not. i want to die

```
mycursor = mydb.cursor()

skuandimages = {
    
}

myquery2 = #insert top secret query here

mycursor.execute(myquery2)

rawskudata = []

c_tag = 0

c_sku = 0
c_img_url = 1
c_name = 2
c_quantity = 3

print(mycursor)

for xy in mycursor:
    for yx in range(2,6):
        rawskudata.append(str(xy[yx]))

print(rawskudata)

for z in range(0,len(rawskudata)):
  #skuandimages[str(x[2]) + "-" + str(x[3])] = x[4]
  c_list = "componant" + str(c_tag)
  skuandimages[c_list] = [rawskudata[int(c_sku)], rawskudata[int(c_img_url)], rawskudata[int(c_name)], rawskudata[int(c_quantity)]]
  #skuandimages[c_list] = [x for x]
  c_sku = c_quantity + 1
  c_img_url = c_quantity + 2
  c_name = c_quantity + 3
  c_quantity = c_quantity + 4
  c_tag += 1
```

The print(rawskudata) returns this (data altered for privacy stuff):

```
['222001-1', 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/64/Garden_strawberry_%28Fragaria_%C3%97_ananassa%29_single.jpg/440px-Garden_strawberry_%28Fragaria_%C3%97_ananassa%29_single.jpg', 'Strawberry', '1', '222014-1', 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/78/Ripe%2C_ripening%2C_and_green_blackberries.jpg/440px-Ripe%2C_ripening%2C_and_green_blackberries.jpg', 'Blackberry', '1', '222053-1', 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e3/Oranges_-_whole-halved-segment.jpg/440px-Oranges_-_whole-halved-segment.jpg', 'Oranges', '1', '222123-1', 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/9e/Autumn_Red_peaches.jpg/440px-Autumn_Red_peaches.jpg', 'Peaches', '1', '222203-1', 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/cf/Pears.jpg/440px-Pears.jpg', 'Pears', '1']
```

Comment: Debugging can be frustrating, and usually, the simpler a  bug, the longer it takes to spot it. Welcome to SO, someone will be able to help. As a first step - could you include the output of `print(rawskudata)` (the statement before the `for z in ...` ) in your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're grabbing data from `rawskudata` 4 at a time, so you want to loop over 1/4 the number of items in `rawskudata`

```
for z in range(0, int(len(rawskudata)/4)):
```

But there is an easier way to go about this. You can replace everything that happens after the line `mycursor.execute(myquery2)` with:

```
for xy in mycursor:
    skuandimages["componant" + str(c_tag)] = [xy[2], xy[3], xy[4], xy[5]]
    c_tag = c_tag + 1
```

---

**Feedback**

Below I've written some feedback on the code you wrote that should hopefully help you out as you learn Python.

When you grab the data

```
for xy in mycursor:
    for yx in range(2,6):
        rawskudata.append(str(xy[yx]))
```

It would be better to use the variable names

```
for row in mycursor:
    for sku_item in range(2,6):
```

While naming might not matter that much in smaller applications, it becomes one of the most important things about writing code in bigger applications, and it also makes things easier if you come back to your code in the future and you're trying to figure out what it does.

The line `rawskudata.append(str(xy[yx]))` converts the data to a string. It's normally best to leave the data as is until you actually need it as a string. That way if you wanted to do something else with it such as comparisons with the product quantities you would have the ability to do so.

On the line `for z in range(0,len(rawskudata)):` instead of using the variable name `z` it is a standard convention to use `i` short for `index` when you grab the index of each item in a list like this, or some people will use the variable name `_` for variables you never actually use in the code. Although it's usually a red flag that you've coded something in a more cumbersome way when you are using the pattern `for i in range(0, len(some_list)):` instead of `for some_value in some_list:`.

In dictionaries like `skuandimages` you have keys and values. The variable `c_list` could be better named `c_key` since it is a dictionary key and not a list.

The line

```
skuandimages[c_list] = [rawskudata[int(c_sku)], rawskudata[int(c_img_url)], rawskudata[int(c_name)], rawskudata[int(c_quantity)]]
```

Doesn't need to convert everything to integers as the numbers are already integers. Perhaps this was just something you added while you trying to figure out the IndexError, but it's unnecessary here. In this situation we would want an error to naturally happen if one of the variables such as c_sku wasn't an integer.

The lines

```
c_sku = c_quantity + 1
c_img_url = c_quantity + 2
c_name = c_quantity + 3
c_quantity = c_quantity + 4
```

Seem odd as you are basing everything off the quantity. I would prefer creating a new variable that has the base value for that iteration, and then you can add +1, +2, +3, +4, etc. to it. It is also more common to get the product fields before you add them to `skuandimages` Something like:

```
product_start_index = 0
for _ in range(0, int(len(rawskudata)/4)):

    sku = rawskudata[product_start_index + 0]
    img_url = rawskudata[product_start_index + 1]
    name = rawskudata[product_start_index + 2]
    quantity = rawskudata[product_start_index + 3]

    key = "component" + product_start_index
    skuandimages[key] = [sku, img_url, name, quantity]

    product_start_index += 4
```

Or, going back to those 4 lines, another alternative would have been

```
c_sku += 4
c_img_url += 4
c_name += 4
c_quantity += 4
```

Adding 4 to those variables each time you go through the loop. (`c_sku += 4` is shorthand for `c_sku = c_sku + 4`). And now there is no need to base the numbers off `c_quantity`

One final improvement. There is a lesser known feature to `range`; a third parameter that allows us to count by 4s instead of counting by 1s. Knowing this we can really make things simple

```
for i in range(0, len(rawskudata), 4):

    sku      = rawskudata[i + 0]
    img_url  = rawskudata[i + 1]
    name     = rawskudata[i + 2]
    quantity = rawskudata[i + 3]

    skuandimages["component" + i] = [sku, img_url, name, quantity]
```

But like I mentioned before, the best solution would be to create `skuandimages` from the beginning instead of `rawskudata`:

```
for xy in mycursor:
    skuandimages["componant" + str(c_tag)] = [xy[2], xy[3], xy[4], xy[5]]
    c_tag = c_tag + 1
```

And if you really want to make things compact, this can be rewritten as

```
for i, product_data in enumerate(mycursor):
    skuandimages["componant " + str(i)] = product_data[2:]
```

`enumerate` will give us both a count, 1, 2, 3, etc. as `i`, each time we loop through the loop, alongside the actual product data. `product_data[2:]` is a shorthand way of getting a sublist starting at the second item and going to the end of the list.

Comment: Beautiful. You are a saint. I was too deep in my head. This works perfectly. Thank you.